# Derivative of $F : \mathbb R^{n+m} \rightarrow \mathbb R^{n+m}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Question :

> > Let f be continously differentiable function on an open set E $\subset \mathbb R^{n+m}$ into $\mathbb R^n$. Define a funtion F on E into $\mathbb R^{n+m}$ such that F(x,y) = (f(x,y),y), where (x,y) $\in E$. Then F is differentiable continous.

I have tried :

Since f is differentiable , so each $(x,y) \in E$, there a matrix A such that $f'(x,y) = A$. Then

$ Lim_{(h,k)\rightarrow0}\frac{|f(x+h, y+k) - f(x,y)|}{|(h,k)|}$ = A

Now $ \frac{|F(x+h, y+k) - F(x,y)|}{|(h,k)|}$ = $\frac{|(f(x+h, y+k),y+k) - (f(x,y),y)|}{|(h,k)|}$

= $ \frac{|(f(x+h, y+k) - f(x,y),k)|}{|(h,k)|}$

please help me how to further solved.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your limit-of quotient definition of derivative doesn't work well in the multi-dimensional case. Note that something goes wrong already at your first displayed equation where you want a limit of quotients of *reals* to be a *matrix*. That is not going to go well.

Rather you're probably looking for a definition that says $f:\mathbb R^k\to\mathbb R^n$ is differentiable at $x$ with derivative $B$ iff
$$ f(x+h) = f(x)+Bh+o(h) $$
as $h\to 0$.

Since you know this holds about $f$, you should be able to construct $A$ as a block matrix that involves $B$ ...